# Why is user_role_change_permissions() throwing an error?

Tags: 7, users

I want to change the permission of anonymous user to view content hits only for a blog section. I came across `user_role_change_permissions()`, but it is throwing an error when I use the following code.

```
 if ($user->uid == "0") {
   $custom_role = user_role_load_by_name('anonymous user'); 
   $custom_rid = $custom_role->rid; 
   $custom_permissions = array(
     'view content hits' => TRUE,
   );
  user_role_change_permissions($custom_rid, $custom_permissions);
 }
```

The error I get is the following:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'module' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {role_permission} (rid, permission, module) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => view content hits [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => ) in user_role_grant_permissions() (line 3154 of C:\xampp\htdocs\capacad\modules\user\user.module).

> Notice: Undefined index: view content hits in user_role_grant_permissions() (line 3152 of C:\xampp\htdocs\capacad\modules\user\user.module).

I tried also with `user_role_grant_permissions()`, but it doesn't work too.

How do I set a new permission for a role?

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
if($user->uid == "0"){
  $custom_role = user_role_load_by_name('anonymous user'); 
  $custom_rid = $custom_role->rid; 
  $custom_permissions = array('view content hits');
  user_role_change_permissions($custom_rid, $custom_permissions);
 }
```

Here you have given

> $custom_permissions = array(
>       'view content hits' => TRUE,   );

TRUE should not be there.

Comment: No, the array needs to be `array( 'view content hits' => TRUE)` as shown in [`user_role_change_permissions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_role_change_permissions/7.x).

Answer (score 1):

As described in [`user_role_change_permissions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_role_change_permissions/7.x), the second argument of `user_role_change_permissions()` (`$permissions`) is:

> An associative array, where the key holds the permission name and the value determines whether to grant or revoke that permission. Any value that evaluates to `TRUE` will cause the permission to be granted. Any value that evaluates to `FALSE` will cause the permission to be revoked.

The array given as example makes clear what that description means.

```
array(
  'administer nodes' => 0,                // Revoke 'administer nodes'
  'administer blocks' => FALSE,           // Revoke 'administer blocks'
  'access user profiles' => 1,            // Grant 'access user profiles'
  'access content' => TRUE,               // Grant 'access content'
  'access comments' => 'access comments', // Grant 'access comments'
)
```

Your code is correct. The problem is that there isn't any module defining the *view content hits* permission. This causes [`user_role_grant_permission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_role_grant_permissions/7.x) to fail since it is using this code.

```
  $modules = user_permission_get_modules();
  // Grant new permissions for the role.
  foreach ($permissions as $name) {
    db_merge('role_permission')
      ->key(array(
        'rid' => $rid,
        'permission' => $name,
      ))
      ->fields(array(
        'module' => $modules[$name],
      ))
      ->execute();
  }
```

Without a module defining that permission, `$modules[$name]` is `NULL`, but the database field for *module* doesn't accept `NULL` values, and Drupal throws that error.
The warming error is caused by the code I shown, which tries to access `$modules['view content hits']` when that is not a defined index for the `$modules` array.

In short, your code is correct, but you need to use a permission that a module is defining in its [`hook_permission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7.x) implementation. It is fine if you set a permission defined by a Drupal core module, or any third-party module. You cannot just set any random permission.

As side note, if the `$user` variable you are using is the global one, you can use the following code.

```
if (user_is_logged_in()) {
   $permissions = array(
     'view content hits' => TRUE,
   );

   $role = user_role_load_by_name('anonymous user'); 
   user_role_change_permissions($role->rid, $permissions);
 }
```

Otherwise, you can just use the following code, keeping in mind what I said in the rest of my answer.

```
if (!$user->uid) {
   $permissions = array(
     'view content hits' => TRUE,
   );

   $role = user_role_load_by_name('anonymous user'); 
   user_role_change_permissions($role->rid, $permissions);
 }
```